# Asynchronous function means no blocking, what about in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous

Asynchronous function means no blocking, and mostly, it keeps with a callback function.
In c# and java, when calling function asynchronously, there must be more than one threads involved. Thus, threads are doing job parallelly, and the callback function will be called when the asynchronous method is finished.

Language like javascript is single thread. So how dose it implement the asynchronous function?

I read some articles and I know it take the event loop and setTimeout function to make a callback. **But is it so-called asynchronous?** Because I don't think it remove the blocking, because it is single thread.
(I know that ajax is real asynchronous,because it use another thread which is supported by browser)

Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Asynchronous calls in Java and C# don't (necessarily) mean that another thread is involved, just that the call sets up a way to continue (often a callback function) and returns as soon as possible to do other work while the operation (for example a disk read) completes.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript run **synchronously** (in one thread), but all I/O operations are **asynchronous**, that means that the calls are non-blocking, and when finished, the callback won't interrupt the running code, but will run synchronously once the current code is finished. So, **it doesn't delay the blocking**.
 Here is an example:

```
console.log("before async call");
setTimeout(function() { console.log("async stuff done"); }, 0);
console.log("after async call");
```

This will **always** display

```
before async call
after async call
async stuff done
```

But now, if you do:

```
console.log("before async call");
setTimeout(function() { console.log("async stuff done"); }, 0);
console.log("after async call");
while (true) {
  // Do nothing
}
```

This will just display:

```
before async call
after async call
```

`async stuff done` is never displayed, because the while (true) lock the execution.

Comment: I agree with what you said mostly. But I regard the function in setTimeout as a block, so in c# or java this block can run in another thread parallelly. But in javascript, this block still runs in the single thread( We all know this function is appended into the event queue), we are not sure the exact time it runs, but we are sure it will run in sometime.So I think the block is delayed.

Answer (score 1):

@Joachim Isaksson: you and I both agree that asynchronous call is no blocking, but in javascript, asynchronous call using setTimeout function just delay the blocking, it never remove the blocking.

```
function f1(callback){
　　　　setTimeout(function () {
　　　　　　// f1's logic
　　　　　　callback();
　　　　}, 1000);
　　}

  f1(f2);
```

As the codes, f1's logic will be delayed and when f1 is finished, it will callback the f2. It looks like asynchronous. But it just delay the blocking.

Comment: There is no *blocking delayed*, because the callback will not interrupt the running code. See my answer.